# Scaling a the plot of a specific function in a plot

Tags: plotting

the following plot is nearly perfect but there at least two question that I would ask?

1) is there a way to rescale the P1 function in such a way that the maximum appears in the graph.

2) I have not found a way to put $\epsilon_0$ at the keft of the axes

```
Evol = {\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(\[Epsilon][t]\)\) == 
C/2 (1 - \[Epsilon][t]) (\[Epsilon][t] - 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\)) \[Epsilon][
  t], \[Epsilon][0] == \[Epsilon]0 + \[Eta]};
H[x_] := C/2 (1 - x) (x - 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\)) x
P0 = Plot[ H[x] /. {C -> 3, 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\) -> .5}, {x, 0, 1}];
P1 = Plot[ Evaluate[ D[H[x], x] /. {C -> 3, 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\) -> .5}], {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> Dashed];
Evol1 = NDSolve[Evol /. {C -> 3, 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\) -> .5, \[Epsilon]0 -> \
.5, \[Eta] -> .05}, \[Epsilon], {t, 0, 100}];
Evol2 = NDSolve[Evol /. {C -> 3, 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\) -> .5, \[Epsilon]0 -> \
.5, \[Eta] -> -.05}, \[Epsilon], {t, 0, 100}];
L1 = Graphics[{Black, Thickness[0.00625], 
Line[{{1, -0.07}, {1, 0.07}}]}];
P11 = ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[{\[Epsilon][t], \[Epsilon]'[t]} /. Evol1], {t, 0, 100}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue! 90, Thickness[.005]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.2, .2}}, Ticks -> None] /.  
Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04}], 
 Arrow[x]};
P21 = ParametricPlot[
Evaluate[{\[Epsilon][t], \[Epsilon]'[t]} /. Evol2], {t, 0, 100}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue! 90, Thickness[.005]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.2, .2}}, Ticks -> None] /.  
Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04}], 
 Arrow[x]};
lText = Text[
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(0\)]\)", 
14], {0.04, -.005}];
cText = Text[
Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\)", 
14], {0.54, -.005}];
rText = Text[
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(1\)]\)", 
14], {0.97, -.005}];
txt = Graphics[{lText, cText, rText}];
Show[P0, P1, P11, P21, L1, txt, 
AxesLabel -> {Style["\[Epsilon]", FontFamily -> "Times", 
FontSize -> 14], 
Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(.\)]\)", 
FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14]}, Ticks -> None, 
BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}], ImageMargins -> 20, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1.05}, {-.07, .07}}, 
Epilog -> {{Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, {Red, 
PointSize[0.02], Point[{{.5, 0}}]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post readable code, e.g. bx getting rid of all unnecessary fany formatting first.

Comment: Try the tips collected here to help you in posting your code: [How to copy code so it looks good on this website](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Look up [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

Answer (score 2):

Showing just the parts relevant to your question, the following modified code should do what you ask.

```
lText = Text[
  Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(0\)]\)", 14], {-0.03, -.02}];
cText = Text[
  Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(_\)]\)", 14], {0.54, -.02}];
rText = Text[
  Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(1\)]\)", 14], {0.97, -.02}];
txt = Graphics[{lText, cText, rText}];
Show[P0, P1, P11, P21, L1, txt,
  AxesLabel ->
    {Style["\[Epsilon]", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14],
     Style["\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(.\)]\)", 
      FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14]},
  Ticks -> None, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}],
  PlotRangePadding -> {{.08, Automatic}, Automatic},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.05}, {-.085, All}}, 
  Epilog -> 
    {{Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{.5, 0}}]}}]
```

[image: plot]

Beside the adjustments to the locations of `lText`, `lText` and `lText`, the things to note are

- The option `PlotRangePadding` is used in place `ImageMargins`.
- The plot range has been adjusted to show the maximum of `P1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
scale = .07/ MaxValue[ D[H[x], x] /. {C -> 3, OverBar[ϵ] -> .5}, x];
P1 = Plot[Evaluate[ scale  D[H[x], x] /. {C -> 3, OverBar[ϵ] -> .5}], {x, 0, 1}, 
         PlotStyle -> Dashed];
lText = Text[Style[Subscript["ϵ", "0"], 14], {-0.04, -.005}];

Show[P0, P1, P11, P21, L1, txt, 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["ϵ", FontFamily -> "Times", 
                FontSize -> 14], Style[Overscript["ϵ", "."], 
                FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 14]}, Ticks -> None, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}], ImageMargins -> 20, 
    PlotRange -> {{-.05, 1.05}, {-.07, .07}}, 
    Epilog -> {{Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, {Red, 
                PointSize[0.02], Point[{{.5, 0}}]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perfect thanks all.